# "coordinating-conjunctions" and "coordination" tags should be synonymized

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

- [coordinating-conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinating-conjunctions)
- [coordination](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordination) Tag wiki says "Questions about coördinating conjunctions, such as “and”, “but”, “or”, “nor”, and “so”."

These seem pretty clearly synonymous. I'd recommend marking "coordinating conjunctions" as a synonym of "coordination" rather than vice versa since the latter already has a tag wiki, and that way we can cover any edge-case questions about coordination without conjunctions.

Comment: I agree. I am confused about the umlaut though.

Comment: @Helmar: It's a dieresis, but yes, it is a bit eccentric.

Comment: Without the letter, sure ;)

Comment: Yes, that's the right way round to do it.

Comment: At present, `coordinating-conjunctions` has a wiki and `coordination` doesn't. So what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be all taken care of now.