# What's going on with the "coordinating-conjunctions" and "coordination" tags?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently asked a question which I tagged with [coordinating-conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinating-conjunctions). When I posted the question, it was automatically changed to [coordination](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordination). I subsequently made an edit, but it was automatically replaced again.

Now, I searched on meta and found [this question that explains why](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9663/coordinating-conjunctions-and-coordination-tags-should-be-synonymized) (the tags have been synonymised). However, the wiki/info for [coordination](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordination) is bare whereas it is not for [coordinating-conjunctions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinating-conjunctions). Shouldn't this be the other way round?

[image]

Comment: If you believe that the *tag wiki should be complete* for "coordination", then I think you're able to suggest an edit to a tag wiki which will fill the gap you have identified (it will need to be approved by a mod or someone with 5k rep). Or: are you suggesting that the *synonym mapping* should be the other way round? (In which case, please make that clear in the question here)

Comment: That is odd. I don't know how it happened

Comment: @AndrewLeach Changing the order should make the other problem moot.